# Which book to choose?

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module, kernel

i learned user space programs(with sys calls and ipc).Now i need to jump into kernel space-building modules and device drivers particularly.I have googled a lot and most sites project codes like rocket science.With what book/pdf can I get a good start?
thanks in advance..

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Naturally rocket science is closely related to space programs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try Robert loves book (3rd Edition, Kernel development), and if you are interested in Linux device drivers (try Oreilly Linux device drivers book, 3rd edition).

Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition by Jonathan Corbet, Alessandro Rubini and Greg Kroah-Hartman

Linux Kernel Development (3rd Edition) by Robert Love.

May be later you can refer

understanding the Linux kernel for more advance stuff.

before doing Kernel programming, do some reading on Operating systems concepts ( THIS IS A GOOD BOOK
Operating System Concepts by Abraham Silberschatz, Peter B. Galvin and Greg Gagne - ANY EDITION)

Those are really good books to start Kernel development.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Tharanga